# Splitting a string by "." doesn't work as expected in AzureDevOps Pipeline

Tags: azure, powershell, split, devops, pipeline

I have this string:

```
$b = "20211118.8"
```

I want to get both values into an array, so I do this:

```
$b = $b -split '\D+'
```

and get the expected result

```
$b[0] = 20211118
$b[1] = 8
```

However, if I let my build pipeline do the same thing it splits every digit into a separate index and I get this:

```
$b[0] = 2
$b[1] = 0
$b[2] = 2
...
```

Why is that and how do I fix it?

Comment: In the bottom of this documentation in the FAQ there is an example of splitting a string on "." - maybe that can help. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops

Comment: `'\D+'` does not contain `.`?

Comment: `$b -split '\.'` or `$b.Split(".")`

Comment: I tried like you suggested @theo but it resulted in the same output

Answer (score 2):

I didn't get it to work like I wanted, but I achieved it like this:

```
$build,$revision = $buildnumber.split(".")
```

Now:

```
$build = 20211118
$revision = 8
```

Comment: While in a comment you say my suggestions do not work, you post it here as a working example...??

Comment: Or are you saying that use of `"` instead of `'` made the difference between your command working and @Theo's not? If so, the implication is that `$b -split "\D+"` (or, more simply, `$b -split "\D"`) and `-split "\."` would work too. Perhaps you can confirm, and update the answer accordingly, including why that made the difference and what the limitations / escaping requirements around `'...'` strings are in Azure.